# Substract one column from one table which contains two types data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table contains quantity column they contains Different Feed_type column,how to display difference of quantity .

```
Select pm.Prod_ID,pm.Product_Name ,ISNULL(Sum(psd.Quantity),0) as Quantity
 into #MyTempTable1 from dbo.[TBL_ProductStock_Details] psd
 inner join dbo.Tbl_Product_master pm  on psd.Prod_ID=pm.Prod_ID where Feed_Type=0 
 GROUP BY  pm.Prod_ID,pm.Product_Name  

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTempTable2
  Select pm.Prod_ID,pm.Product_Name ,ISNULL(Sum(psd.Quantity),0) as Quantity 
into #MyTempTable2 from dbo.[TBL_ProductStock_Details] psd 
inner join dbo.Tbl_Product_master pm  on psd.Prod_ID=pm.Prod_ID  where Feed_Type=1 
 GROUP BY  pm.Prod_ID,pm.Product_Name

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTempTable3          
SELECT #MyTempTable1.Prod_ID as Prod_ID,#MyTempTable1.Product_Name as Product_Name ,
ISNULL(#MyTempTable1.Quantity,0) -ISNULL(#MyTempTable2.Quantity,0) AS Quantity_Diff 
into #MyTempTable3 from #MyTempTable1 
join #MyTempTable2 on 1=1 and #MyTempTable1.Prod_ID=#MyTempTable2.Prod_ID ;  

Select * From #MyTempTable3
```

Comment: Cannot understand what you mean by 'contains quantity column they contains Different Feed_type ,how to display difference of quantity if available other wise set 0.' Can you paraphrase please?

Comment: i have one column name quantity which storing two types data  we want to display difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *conditional aggregation* to simplify the logic and perform the operations in a single query:

```
SELECT 
    pm.Prod_ID,
    pm.Product_Name,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Feed_Type = 0 THEN psd.Quantity ELSE 0 END), 0)
        - ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Feed_Type = 1 THEN psd.Quantity ELSE 0 END), 0) AS Quantity_Diff 
INTO #MyTempTable3
FROM 
    dbo.[TBL_ProductStock_Details] psd
    INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Product_master pm  
        ON psd.Prod_ID = pm.Prod_ID
WHERE Feed_type IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY 
    pm.Prod_ID,
    pm.Product_Name
```

Depending on the distribution of `NULLs` in the `Quantity` column, it might also be possible to simplify furthermore with a single `SUM()`:

```
SELECT 
    pm.Prod_ID,
    pm.Product_Name,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN Feed_Type = 0 THEN ISNULL(psd.Quantity, 0) 
        ELSE -1 * ISNULL(psd.Quantity, 0) 
    END) AS Quantity_Diff 
INTO #MyTempTable3
FROM 
    dbo.[TBL_ProductStock_Details] psd
    INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Product_master pm  
        ON psd.Prod_ID = pm.Prod_ID
WHERE Feed_type IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY 
    pm.Prod_ID,
    pm.Product_Name
```

Note: consider indexing column `Feed_type` with the table it belongs to; as you query is, this cannot be told, which makes it less easy to understand.